# Unable to align user chats using php query

Tags: php, chat

I have the following table named 'user_chats', which has the following columns and data;

```
id - message_id - from_user_id - for_user_id - message - time_sent
1     sW2ja_29s        11            20           Hi       2:00am
2     sW2ja_29s        20            11         Hello      2:02pm
```

I am finding it difficult to align messages sent by logged in user (with id 11) to the right and message sent by other user (with id 20) to the left with my query just like how Facebook and other social network do there's. Below is a query I wrote that fetch chats between two users after being unable to solve the problem.

```
<?php
    $message_id = $_GET['msg_id'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users_chats WHERE message_id = ? ORDER BY time_sent ASC";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $query);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $message_id);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $chats = $row['message'];
        }

        // chats
        echo $chats;
?>
```

Comment: Where is your html?

Comment: Sorry for that, but by adding a css style code like float-right/float-left to  `$chats` I only get all messages aligned to the right/left. @Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your `while` loop is redundant.
Inside the `while` loop you only assign the message value from the last element of the result to `$chat`.

To solve the issue you need an identifier from the person which receives the messages or from the person which sends the messages to move the message to the right or to the left.